# Enumerable.Skip and ordering

Tags: c#, linq

So `IEnumerable`s don't guarantee order.

Does that mean if you do `myEnumerable.Skip(5)` you cannot (unless you do `.ToList()` or otherwise before) guarantee what will be returned?

Comment: `IEnumerable` is an interface. it doesn't guarantee anything.

Comment: the order of elements in `IEnumerable` *normally* would be the looping order when you use `foreach` on that `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @I4V doesn't it guarantee a `IEnumerator GetEnumerator()` method?

Comment: It doesn't guarantee order because it can't.  When you find a programmer that implemented MoveNext() by moving backwards then use the New York Times to whack him over the head.  Sunday edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether a *particular* ordering is guaranteed or not by any specdific `IEnumerable<T>` is dependent on

- How that particular implementation is/was done, and on
- the semantics of the underlying collection/class.

An array will enumerate its contents in the obvious sequence (from `x[0]` to `x[n]`.) Ditto for a `List<T>`, it being essentially an array of adjustable length. Actual [linked] lists, of course, can only be enumerated in order.

The order of enumeration of `Dictionary<K,V>`, `HashSet<T>`, binary trees, etc. is dependent upon the order in which objects were added. Add the same collection of values with differing orderings to a binary tree and the structure of the tree thus constructed will vary (the degenerate case, of course, being when objects are added in order, in which case the tree structure collapsed into an [ordered] linked list.

That being said, any particular instance of `IEnumerable<T>`, should, barring any modifications to the underlying collection, yield the same sequence of values each time it is enumerated. That assumes, of course, a rational implementation of the interface. If the interface enumerates the collection by doing a random shuffle, of course, all bets are off.

If the *actual* order of items produced is important, you need to either

- Use a collection having the desired semantics, or
- Enforce the desired ordering by sorting the collection or enumeration.

Answer (score 5):

Once the objects are yielded by an `IEnumerator` they *do* have an order.  There is some item that comes out first, and some item that comes out second, etc.  For some particular implementations that order might have meaning, for others it might be arbitrary, but there still is some order.  The `Skip` implementation is straightforward; it gets however many items without yielding them, and then gets the rest and yields them.  Whether the items skipped mean anything in particular is the responsibility of whoever is calling the method.

Calling `ToList` will never change the order of the items in the sequence, so adding such a call before calling `Skip` wouldn't change anything.  A call to `OrderBy` on the other hand would result in a changed ordering, possibly from a meaningless order to a meaningful order.  That's not to say it's *required*, merely that it can, in some situations, be a useful tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Skip(x)`, the first `x` elements will be ignored and everything after will be returned in a new `IEnumerable<T>`. The interface makes no guarantees that it will retain order but in practice it does. Anytime you operate on an `IEnumerable<T>` it will actually go through the same list in a linear fashion. For example if you read a file line by line into and `IEnumerable<T>` the lines would always be in the same order as they were in the file (assuming you don't use a sorting method). Even if you use a `Where` or some other method to filter the results, order will still be retained. The only thing you need to worry about is custom collections that implement `IEnumerable<T>`. The collections in .NET will behave as you'd expect them to.

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerable is an *interface*. As such, the interface has no guarantee of order. However, if you have an actual *object* that implements that interface, that object *may* (and often does) guarantee the order.